# Build issue: HTTP Listener build fail

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

When I try to build an empty project I am getting the follow error. I use JDK 17. Can someone help me with this issue? Do I need to change JDK version? When I add an HTTP Listener and build the code I am getting below error:

> mvn clean package -nsu -DskipMunitTest has encountered a problem

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not use screenshots for logs and text information. Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557 for more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error "Unsupported class file major version 61" trying to start Mule 4.4 in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71786660/getting-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-61-trying-to-start-mule-4-4)